# How do I simplify this Laws Of Logic question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So far I have done most of the work, but I have hit a wall.... I jist cant seem to get past these few steps to get the final answer. Can someone help me figure out the last few steps. I have spent about 1 hour trying to figure it out and you can see my apparent eraser marks of despair.... Help is truely needed.[image]

Comment: $(p+\bar{q})(\bar{p}r + q(p+r)) = (p+\bar{q})(\bar{p}r) + (p+\bar{q})q(p+r)$ - you converted an and into an or...

Comment: Is that right..., I will try again then

Comment: I am confused more now...How should I continue from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  (p+\bar{q})(\bar{p}r + q(p+r)) &= (p+\bar{q})(\bar{p}r) + (p+\bar{q})q(p+r) \\
    &= \bar{p}\bar{q}r + (pq + q\bar{q})(p+r) \\
    &= \bar{p}\bar{q}r + pq(p+r) \\
    &= \bar{p}\bar{q}r + pq
\end{align*}

Comment: I am sorry but, how did we go expand the first two and get -p-qr?

Comment: nvm, I THINK i did the steps to get what ou did.